# Arch linux freezes when unplugged

Tags: linux, multi-boot, arch-linux

I have a dual-boot of Windows 11 and EndeavourOS, The problem occurs when I unplug the charger it freezes after some time not immediately, but this does not happen when the pc is plugged in. I have also tried downgrading the Linux kernel but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Please, add to your post the **laptop model**.

Comment: Try to check **battery health** out. Look at this article: [How to Check Your Laptop's Battery Health in Linux](https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-check-your-laptops-battery-health-in-linux/)

Comment: K, I didn’t fix the issue but switched to the zen kernel and works fine without any problem.

Comment: Good, now try **to reinstall the previous kernel** that's preseting the issue itself and do some testing to know confirming what that was exactly. Just a suggestion.